# what does FindClass("..","[I") do?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I came across the following snippet :

```
jobjectArray result;
 int i;
 jclass intArrCls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"[I"); // will return an array class
 if(intArrCls == NULL) {
     return NULL;
 }
 result = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,size,intArrCls,NULL);
```

In the above snippet what does `(*env)->FindClass(env,"[I")` return ? what does `"[I"` denote ? I checked the DOCS but didn't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *what does `"[I"` denote ?*

`[I` is the bytecode notation for the type `int[]`.

This is, among other places, documented here: [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29)

Comment: it returns the class object that represent 1-D int array (int[])

Comment: Presumably it returns the *class* representing a one-dimensional integer array.